What is the (smallest) setup to allow import to be used by Jest?
I'm having trouble running a module test in Node. I don't have an existing project, and I can't find one that has tests using import statements.
In  Jest's Getting Started guide, there is a line that I want to use: import {sum} from './sum';
When I use that instead of const sum = require('./sum'); it errors with:
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { sum } from './sum';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Given I've successfully followed the instructions in the first section before "Additional Configuration", what are the minimum changes required to get the import statement working?
(Node 22.8.0, jest 29.7.0, ts-jest 29.2.5) - it shouldn't be experimental any more?

https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules, https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support/

@jonrsharpe Shall I presume you voted down and to close? Do you expect that getting a basic ("getting started") test running should require reading multiple screens of information (of which neither show a simple fix)? A very basic question should have a basic answer (see mine below, which I hadn't seen answered on the internet, despite many having a similar issue) - or is JS development unnecessarily complicated to manage?

Well, it seems like transpiling is still required to get this to work.
The key thing is to update the package.json to include
  "jest":{
     "preset": "ts-jest"
  }

that preset line could be replaced with:
  transform: {
    "^.+.tsx?$": ["ts-jest",{}]
  }

(at least for the purposes of fixing the import statement issue)

I really wish downvoters could share what's wrong with an answer - is there something incorrect or even non-optimal in the above? I still don't know why it's not a valid/useful answer (it seemed to be the only easy solution I could find...)
